# Set href using $root value within foreach loop

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, href

The link in the first `td` column spazzes out when trying to bind to `$root.rootBaseUrl`.

In the second `td` column, the same `rootBaseUrl` observable prints perfectly.

The difference is that in the first `td` column, I am trying to set the value within `attr:`.

Also, please note that there is a `foreach` loop happening at the `tbody` level. Hence the use of `$root` prefix.

```html
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: siteList">        
        <tr>
            <td><h3><a data-bind="text: SiteName, attr: {href: $root.rootBaseUrl + SiteID}"></a></h3></td>                
            <td><h3><span data-bind="text: $root.rootBaseUrl"></span></h3></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

```js
var rootBaseUrl = ko.observable("");
var index = window.location.toString().indexOf("RiskOrder");
var baseURL = window.location.toString().substring(0, index);               
this.rootBaseUrl(baseURL);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Basically, I am getting the current browser URL in the JS, stripping it to the base root url, then trying to add this static URL to the `href` binding and concatenating with a dynamic `SiteID` value.

Is this possible?

Comment: For the first `td` it should have a `()` in `$root.rootBaseUrl`. So it's gonna be `{href: $root.rootBaseUrl() + SiteID}`, if `SiteID` is also an observable then same goes to it, it should have `()`

Comment: What does "spazzes out" even mean? Please be precise (and think that readers might not be native English speakers who don't know this kind of slang). Also, you have 90% of a working sample that could potentially demonstrate the issue, why stop there? Put in the missing 10% so that something actually happens when you click that "Run code snippet" button.

Comment: @tomalak - agree with you completely. It was a long stuck and was late at night and very tired when I posted this. Thanks for the notes.

Comment: Remember it for next time. Asking a question well enough so that a future reader can benefit from it is your responsibility. You never know who's day you save by putting in the extra effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `attr` with `text` and get a glimplse of your problem:

```js
function Vm(){
  var self = this;
  self.SiteID = ko.observable("AX123");
}

function RootVm(){
  var self = this;
  var index = window.location.toString().indexOf("RiskOrder");
  var baseURL = window.location.toString().substring(0, index);
  
  self.rootBaseUrl = ko.observable("");
  self.SiteName = ko.observable("My Site");
  self.rootBaseUrl(baseURL);
  self.SiteList = ko.observableArray([new Vm()]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new RootVm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: SiteList">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3><a data-bind="text: $root.rootBaseUrl + SiteID"></a></h3>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h3><span data-bind="text: $root.rootBaseUrl"></span></h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It renders `function.....`, so a textual representation of a function. This is because `rootBaseUrl` is a function. If you want to use it in an expression, you *have* to use parentheses:

```
<h3><a data-bind="text: $root.rootBaseUrl()+ SiteID()"></a></h3>
```

If you use it as the *only* thing in a binding, the parentheses are *optional*:

```
<h3><span data-bind="text: $root.rootBaseUrl()"></span></h3>
```

So your fix would be:

```js
function Vm(){
  var self = this;
  self.SiteID = ko.observable("AX123");
  self.SiteName = ko.observable("My Site");
}

function RootVm(){
  var self = this;
  var index = window.location.toString().indexOf("RiskOrder");
  var baseURL = window.location.toString().substring(0, index);
  
  // On SO Snippets window.location works differently so we hack it:
  baseURL = "https://example.com/my-website/url/";
  
  self.rootBaseUrl = ko.observable("");
  self.rootBaseUrl(baseURL);
  self.SiteList = ko.observableArray([new Vm()]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new RootVm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: SiteList">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3><a data-bind="text: SiteName, attr: { href: $root.rootBaseUrl() + SiteID() }"></a></h3>
    </td>
    <td>
      Second column
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or use a computed so you can (a) unit test the logic and (b) make the parentheses optional again:

```js
function Vm(urlBaseVm){
  var self = this;
  self.SiteID = ko.observable("AX123");
  self.SiteName = ko.observable("My Site");
  
  self.hrf = ko.computed(function() {
    return urlBaseVm.rootBaseUrl() + self.SiteID();
  });
}

function RootVm(){
  var self = this;
  var index = window.location.toString().indexOf("RiskOrder");
  var baseURL = window.location.toString().substring(0, index);
  
  // On SO Snippets window.location works differently so we hack it:
  baseURL = "https://example.com/my-website/url/";
  
  self.rootBaseUrl = ko.observable("");
  self.rootBaseUrl(baseURL);
  self.SiteList = ko.observableArray([new Vm(self)]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new RootVm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: SiteList">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3><a data-bind="text: SiteName, attr: { href: hrf }"></a></h3>
    </td>
    <td>
      Second column
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: yeah, it was the $root.rootBaseUrl() ... I needed the () after. But pretty sure I tried this yesterday. This morning, I rebuilt the code piece by piece until I got it working. Maybe my cache wasn't clearing during debug, I don't know. Appreciate the reply, thanks!